# Chain Classifiers in R

Tags: r, binary-tree, multilabel-classification, mlr

Is there any way to perform chain classification in multi-label classification problem. I have created a binary relevance model using mlr package which uses learners to achieve the same. But all the classification models in binary relevance are independent of each other and does not take into consideration the inter-dependencies of variables.
It would be really helpful if I can perform chain classification along with binary relevance method to improve my model.

Comment: The wrappers in mlr don't allow you to do this directly, but there is a [ChainModel](https://github.com/mlr-org/mlr/blob/master/R/ChainModel.R) that you can use for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

We have multilabel classification with other algorithms like Classifier Chains now available in mlr, checkout the updated tutorial: http://mlr-org.github.io/mlr-tutorial/release/html/multilabel/index.html

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.